# How to create a derived query method in Spring Data JPA Repositories to find on a list

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jpa

I have an JPA entity that looks like this:

```kotlin
data class Entity(
    @Id
    val id: UUID,
    val anotherId: UUID,
    @Column(name = "list_of_ids", columnDefinition = "uuid[]")
    val listOfIds: List<UUID>,
)
```

And as a final result I would like to make a search to gather a list of Entities matching given `anotherId` and one (1) id from the `listOfIds`.

So at my EntityRepository I tried to do this:

```kotlin
interface EntityRepository : JpaRepository<PromiseEntity, UUID> {

    fun findByListOfIdsAndAnotherId(listOfIds: UUID, anotherId: UUID): List<Entity>
}
```

Obviously it does not work, otherwise I would not be here.
I am not sure how this can be done? I never found any specific documentation for how to deal with lists in derived query methods (I am sorry if the term is not correct, I got it from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries))

To be specific: is there any way to write a derived query method to return a list of entities querying from a property that is a list but only giving one parameter?

> The actual names of the variables and classes were hidden for privacy reasons

By the way, when I run my componentTests I get the following error, that I will summarize with the important part:

```bash
Operator SIMPLE_PROPERTY on listOfIds requires a scalar argument, found interface ...findByListOfIdsAndAnotherId(java.util.List,java.util.UUID).
```

Comment: This is not the ideal way to do it. You should create a separate class to store the list of Ids and  map it with the entity class with @OneToMany annotation

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this and then write the jpa query

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entity")
public class Entity{

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart")
    private List<ListofIds> Ids;
    
    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="listofids")
public class ListOfIds {
    
    // Some code
    @ManyToOne
    private Entity entity;

    public Entity() {}
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not feasible to change our database and remove the list to another table... The ideal thing is only to change the JPA declaration method... But I believe it would be necessary to create a custom SQL right?